# Having menu toggle vertical instead of horizontal for navbar toggle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Code Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a8hu4Lo1/

I am unable to have the menu toggle ul/li tags drop down and be in a vertical formation.  They are horizontal.

How can I create this so it is vertical?

I tried both:

```
 .nav-li  {
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .nav-li  {
   display: block;
 }
```

Along with variations of:

```
 .nav-li div  {
  ...;
 }
```

I tried it on the ul as well.

The ul is:

```
 .div_underline {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

How to make the toggle menu drop down into a vertical li format?

Comment: Are you intending to have one of your links outside of the menu at mobile screens?  Because your navbar markup is all sorts of messed up.

Comment: Haha yes.  That's where something else goes.  It's in rails so i had to qucikly convert it to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added below css

```
.navbar-collapse .navbar-expand{
 flex-direction: column;
}
```

check below link
https://jsfiddle.net/8gz1x7m4/

Comment: Thanks.  Works how i want with a @media query for screen size for when it appears (the toggle).

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .navbar-collapse .navbar-expand{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.